# Is $T$ an (expansive) homeomorphism?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X=\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ and on it the following dynamics described by $T\colon X\to X$ as follows: A 1 becomes a 2, a 2 becomes a 0 and a 0 becomes a 1 if at least one of its two neighbors is 1.

Moreover, consider
$$
Y=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}T^n(X).
$$

My question is if $T$ is an expansive homeomorphism?

I think it isn't a homeomorphism at all... so in particular no expansive homeomorphism.

Comment: Are you asking whether $T$ is an expansive homeomorphism, or whether $T\upharpoonright Y$ is an expansive homeomorphism?

Comment: Both to be honest.

Comment: For $X$ it’s not hard: see my answer. I’ll have to think about $T\upharpoonright Y$; before I do, what metric are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT for $T$: Let $x=\langle 0,0,0,\ldots\rangle$ and $y=\langle 2,2,2,\ldots\rangle$; what are $T(x)$ and $T(y)$?